# How do I align this border?

Tags: css, alignment, border

This is what I have so far: http://jsfiddle.net/u8GHJ/

What I'm trying to do is attach the black border to the left side of the blue box. What is an easy way to achieve this? And no, I can't just add `border-left:4px solid black;` to `#container li`.

It should look like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oLBK8.png

Edit: I need to move the border to the container and not the opposite, so setting the padding to 0 won't help in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's default padding on the `ul` element. To remove it, add `ul {padding:0;}` ( or `#container {padding:0;}`) to your css and every thing will look peachy.

Check out your updated example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/agconti/u8GHJ/1/

Comment: This is very helpful, didn't know this. Though I forgot to mention I need to bring the border to the container and not the container to the border.

Comment: @0x0700 I think it would be better practice to remove the padding on the `ul` and then position the feature accordingly. To position it, you could add padding or positioning to another container `div` or just the border `div`. Using a container like this will work http://jsfiddle.net/agconti/u8GHJ/6/

Comment: What would be the best way to center the two elements?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The container assumes the dimensions of its content so everything should be "centered" within it. Centering the container with other content would probably be worth a new question though. If I answered this question, can you please accept my answer?

Answer (score 1):

`ul` have default `padding`Give this a try to resolve your problem:

```
#container{
    padding:0;
}
```

[**<kbd>JS Fiddle</kbd>**](http://jsfiddle.net/u8GHJ/2/)

Answer (score 0):

I have solved your problem. Just add css property of ul

```
ul{
    padding:0px;
  }
```

[Click here for DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/u8GHJ/4/)